# Number subsections and subsubsections, but not sections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm working on an article and I don't want to number my sections. However, I do want my subsections and subsubsections to be numbered. 
Right now my document has this numbering, but the 0 in 0.X.Y should not be there. How can I fix that?

```
Currently:
Section
0.1 subsection
0.2 subsection
0.2.1 subsubsection
0.3 subsection

Should be:
Section
1. subsection
2. subsection
2.1 subsubsection
3. subsection
```

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}

\subsection{subsection}

\subsection{subsection}

\subsubsection{subsubsection}
blah
\subsection{subsection}

\end{document}
```

PS: I *did* search a on the web and found a lot on this topic, but not a solution to this particular thing.

Comment: What should happen after a 2nd `\section*`? Should the numbering start again at 1 or should it continue?

Answer (score 26):

If you're interested in printing `\section{<heading>}` in a similar way that `\section*{<heading>}` would print (that is, flush left and not indented), then [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) provides an easy interface:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\titleformat{\section}%
  [hang]% <shape>
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Large}% <format>
  {}% <label>
  {0pt}% <sep>
  {}% <before code>
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}% Remove section references...
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}%... from subsections
\begin{document}

\section{First section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sollicitudin rutrum tellus, 
eu luctus dolor commodo eu. Integer pellentesque mollis congue.

\subsection{First subsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sollicitudin rutrum tellus, 
eu luctus dolor commodo eu. Integer pellentesque mollis congue.

\subsection{Second subsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sollicitudin rutrum tellus, 
eu luctus dolor commodo eu. Integer pellentesque mollis congue.

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sollicitudin rutrum tellus, 
eu luctus dolor commodo eu. Integer pellentesque mollis congue.

\subsection{Last subsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sollicitudin rutrum tellus, 
eu luctus dolor commodo eu. Integer pellentesque mollis congue.

\section{Second section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sollicitudin rutrum tellus, 
eu luctus dolor commodo eu. Integer pellentesque mollis congue.

\subsection{First subsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sollicitudin rutrum tellus, 
eu luctus dolor commodo eu. Integer pellentesque mollis congue.

\end{document}​
```

This just sets the label separator between the section number and title to `0pt`, as well as not printing the number. `\normalfont\bfseries\Large` is the default formatting for [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls).

Comment: Hmm, using this I get no numbers on my subsections either.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, it is a bug in titlesec: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299969/46021

Comment: Actually, only the two `\renewcommand` are necessary to answer the question.

Comment: The `\titleformat` bit is there to remove the space that would otherwise still be printed after the (now empty) the section number. Without it, all section headings would appear indented.

Answer (score 17):

Note: I rewrote this answer significantly after becoming aware of Ulrike Fisher's comment to @knut's answer.

There are two steps that need to be taken. The first, straightforward step consists of redefining the `\thesubsection` macro. The second, less obvious step involves a redefinition of the LaTeX internal macro `\@seccntformat`, as is explained in the book *The LaTeX Companion*, 2nd ed. The following MWE applies both steps:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{}     % section level 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\subsection{Third subsection}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{A new subsection}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address @Adam's follow-up question: To (a) add dots after the subsection (and subsubsection) numbers in the sectioning headers and (b) replace the implicit `\quad` spacing directive with `\space`, you would need to provide the following two directives in the preamble, immediately before `\makeatother`:

```
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\space}
\newcommand\subsubsection@cntformat{\thesubsubsection.\space}
```

A revised MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{}     % section level 
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\space} % subsection level
\newcommand\subsubsection@cntformat{\thesubsubsection.\space} % subsubsection level
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\subsection{Third subsection}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{A new subsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But without the redefinition of `\thesection` you still get a numbered section. See also my answer.

Comment: I understand. Then you have the same problem Ulrike mentioned: This will not restart the numbering of the `\subsections` after the next `\section*` - but there is no information in the question, what's needed in this case.

Comment: @knut: I just noticed the comment by Ulrike Fisher to your answer. She's right about having to use `\section` rather than `\section*`, as otherwise subsection numbers won't get reset in a new section. As my (now thoroughly revised) answer that's based on some code from *The LaTeX Companion* shows, what's really needed to solve the OP's challenge is both a redefinition of `\@seccntformat` and a new macro, `\section@cntformat` -- set here to `{}`. Interestingly, it is *not* necesssary to set `\thesection` to something like `{}`. Whew, this was a lot harder than it looked like at first!

Comment: That is great. However, how can I add the period after the subsection number and keep only one space after? I think "1. First subsection" would look better.

Comment: @Adam - Please see the addendum I posted to my answer. It provides the code needed to implement your formatting objective for subsection- and subsubsection-level headers.

Comment: @Mico I may be missing something obvious, but where can I find the addendum? I see your answer and your response to knut only.

Comment: @Adam - Umm, I see the addendum just fine. It starts with the string "Addendum to address Adam's follow-up question". Does reloading the page maybe help?

Comment: It might be good to note that with this solution, section numbers do still show up in the table of contents (if you have one).

Comment: @Circumscribe - Thanks. If having to produce a table of contents is required, I would suggest inserting `\usepackage{tocloft} \makeatletter \renewcommand\cftsecpresnum{\@gobble} \makeatother` in the preamble. It may be desirable to tweak the appearance of the ToC beyond this minimalist step. E.g., one could further run `\setlength\cftsecnumwidth{0em} \setlength\cftsubsecindent{0em} \setlength\cftsubsecnumwidth{1.5em} \setlength\cftsubsubsecindent{1.5em} \setlength\cftsubsubsecnumwidth{2em}`. Before getting too specific, though, I'd rather hear back from the OP first.

Comment: @Mico – The OP was last seen in December of 2011 and they never got around to accepting any of the answers, so I think the chance of a reply from them is likely slim :) / :(.

Comment: @Circumscribe -- Well, are *you* satisfied with the additional information I provided?

Comment: @Mico – I am. This completely fixes the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Does this works for you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\part*{Section}

\section{subsection}

\section{subsection}

\subsection{subsubsection}
blah
\section{subsection}

\end{document}
```

Or is there a special reason, why you need sections as sections and subsections as subsection?

---

Alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{subsection}

\subsection{subsection}

\subsubsection{subsubsection}
blah
\subsection{subsection}

\section{Section 2}

\subsection{subsection 2}
This subsection starts again with 1.


\end{document}
```

Comment: That does the job, but the size is rather large now. Can you tell me how to keep it the same size as the sections? Thanks :)

Comment: This will not restart the numbering of the `\subsection`s after the next `\section*`.

Comment: You are right - but it works with `\section`. I change my answer.