# How to remove "zero" preceding section number?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, sections-paragraphs

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\let\stdl@section\l@section
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
  \stdl@section{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}}
\let\stdl@subsection\l@subsection
\renewcommand*{\l@subsection}[2]{%
  \stdl@subsection{\textcolor{DarkGreen}{#1}}{\textcolor{DarkGreen}{#2}}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{chapter1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter1}
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\section{Section Two}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\end{document}
```

Now it has a preceding `zero` in front of the section numbers. How can I get rid of zero. For reference I am attaching an image as well. [image]

Comment: People who come across this question *might* be looking for [sectioning - Number subsections and subsubsections, but not sections - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37189/number-subsections-and-subsubsections-but-not-sections) instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

this will get rid of the zero and period in both the toc and the body of the document:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{%
  \ifnum\c@chapter<1 \@arabic\c@section
  \else \thechapter.\@arabic\c@section
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

this assumes that the chapter counter is already properly defined, as it is in the book and report classes.

Answer (score 22):

Add this to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

This line above removes the chapter number from the section number. Unchanged, this would look something like

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
```

The changed output:

[image: screenshot 1]

and

[image: screenshot 2]