# Section numbers have a zero in front with report document class

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sections-paragraphs, report

I wrote my tex file first in `article` mode. Now that I switched the document class to `report`, unfortunately I am getting a zero before my sections and subsections which I want to be removed. Changing `secnumdepth` completely removes the number for subsections but as I said I only want that zero to dispersal.

My code is:

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper] {report}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\section{One}

\subsection{one-one}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why did you (have to) switch to `report`? The only difference would be the availability of `\chapter`s, which it seems you're not interested in.

Comment: This question is ever so close to being a duplicate of [TOC - How to remove "zero" preceding section number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45150) – what does everybody else think?

Comment: I didn't know the difference is this little.

Comment: @Naji For more about the standard document classes, see [book vs. report vs. article document class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36988).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sectional units have their numbering slated as `<chapter>.<section>` and defined (within [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls)) as

```
\renewcommand \thesection {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
```

If you wish to modify this and remove the `<chapter>` component, add

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

to your document preamble.