# Start new page with each part

Tags: page-breaking, titlesec, parts

How can I automatically start a new page with each `part`?

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section), which work nicely for section breaks, but was unable to customize the command to works with `parts`.

I looked the [`titlesec` documentation](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf), but it wasn't apparent to me how to use the package to start a new page for `parts`.

Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{libertine} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{floatrow} \floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage[verbose,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm, headsep=1.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} \lhead{\includegraphics[width=1cm] ./figures/logo.jpg}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage} %new page after each section
```

Comment: Do you have to use the `article` class? Simply changing to `report` will work.

Comment: Don't parts always start a new page?

Comment: Changing to `report` class did work, but changes the section enumeration (now listed from 0.1, 0.2, ... instead of 1, 2, 3...).  Any way to make it happen with an `article` class?

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45156/24974) shows how to remove the zero preceding the section number. However, if you don't want an entire part page, which the `report` class will create, then Ian's answer should work nicely.

Comment: @erik - your link to the section numbering is handy too, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text
\let\oldpart\part
\renewcommand\part{\newpage\oldpart}
\begin{document}
\part{The first}
\lipsum[1-2]
\part{The second}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `etoolbox` you can apply a `\clearpage` before `\part`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\part}{\clearpage}
\title{Some}
\author{you}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\part{The first}
\lipsum[1-2]
\part{The second}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```