# Numbering of items in a chapter

Tags: theorems, counters

I am writing my thesis with book class. All but one of the chapters have subsection. For the particular chapter without a subsection, the first definition number comes as 2.0.1. The 0 is for the subsection. How do I make it just 2.1 instead of 2.0.1? Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass[oneside, openany,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,latexsym,amsfonts,mathrsfs,graphics,graphicx,amssymb}

\usepackage[mathcal]{eucal}

\usepackage{setspace,titlesec,float,indentfirst,tocloft}

\usepackage[top=1in, left=1in, bottom=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\LARGE}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~}

\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\qquad}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}

\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{5.8em}

\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{6.1em}

\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.1em}

\renewcommand{\cftsubsecindent}{6.1em}

\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{2.1em}

\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{mthm}[thm]{Main Theorem}

\newtheorem{clm}[thm]{Claim}

\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}

\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{Remark}\theoremstyle{remark}

\newtheorem{exm}[thm]{Example}\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{case}[thm]{Case}\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\chapter{CHAPTER WITH NO SUBSECTION}

\defn blah blah blah
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is incomplete

Comment: From your example I can't see the place where `subsection` counter is used at all

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I have. I don't know how to fix it. Sorry.

Comment: related (similar, not duplicate): [How to remove “zero” preceding section number?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45150/579)

Comment: @ barbara beeton: Thanks a lot. It worked! You're awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Redefine `\thethm` to not add the section number if it's 0.

```
\documentclass[oneside, openany,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}

\renewcommand{\thethm}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0
    \thechapter.%
  \else
    \thesection.%
  \fi
  \arabic{thm}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\begin{defn}
blah blah blah
\end{defn}


\chapter{Another}
\section{Title}

\begin{thm}
Blah blah
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Note that you should use `\begin{defn}` and `\end{defn}`, not `\defn`.

I left only the relevant code, add back the rest you need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had similiar issues with the numbering of image captions.
Maybe the package `chngcntr` could help you.

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
...
\chapter{CHAPTER WITH NO SUBSECTION}
\counterwithout{defn}{section}
\defn blah blah blah
```