# subsection without section's number

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Hello i'm trying to write subsection without section's number.And I need to write section's number in roman numeral(i already found this one using `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}`) But when i using these, roman numeral appears in front of subsections number how do I write subsection without sections number but section and subsections number appears in `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: Hi Mr./Mrs. Downvoter ask for clarification to OP and Please care to leave for the downvote atleast for first timer here

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format

Comment: There is a more extensive answer at [question 37189](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37189/number-subsections-and-subsubsections-but-not-sections). This might help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Subsection number representation is provided by `\thesubsection` which, by default, is defined as

```
\newcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
```

Redefining it to

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
```

removes the preceding `\thesection.`. Subsection numbering will still be reset with every section.