# How do I modify my ToC to start with the subsection?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have the following problem. At the moment I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\subsection{section}
\subsubsection{subsection}
\paragraph{subsubsection}
\subparagraph{paragraph}

\end{document}
```

Compiled the toc looks like this:

[image]

But I need it like this:

[image]

So I want, that the paragraphs list as subsubsections, the subsubsections list as subsections and the subsections list as sections in my toc.

Comment: Do you have  no section?

Comment: No sections, because I have to include them from other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Werner's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126623/85946), you can redefine your `\subsection` command

```latex
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
```

and then with

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\subsection{section}
\subsubsection{subsection}
\paragraph{subsubsection}
\subparagraph{paragraph}

\end{document}
```

you get

[image: subsection toc]