# Number subsections without numbering sections

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I'm trying to replicate the ARGUMENT section pictured below.

[image: here]

I tried adapting the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839647/latex-how-to-change-one-of-section-numbers-to-a-custom-letter?rq=1) for the letters but I found that when I suppress the section numbers the subsection numbers do not properly print.

Comment: Hi. Does the code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37221/156366) do what you want?

Comment: Not exactly, but I was able to create the following 
`\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Alph{subsubsection}}`
This does everything except the dot after the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed, with the following working code:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Alph{subsubsection}}

\let \savenumberline \numberline
\def \numberline#1{\savenumberline{#1.}}
```

Later code from [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13045).

Comment: Very good. Please be advised, however, that if you don't also change the formatting of the section headings the space following the (now empty) section number will still be printed in the headings themselves. This is done e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37221/156366) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37192/156366).

Comment: I've found that I actually have to suppress the section anyway with `\section*` and add it in `\addcontentsline` because the dot from the last two lines of code will print before the section even though there is no numbering, not sure how to fix that in the "correct" way.

Comment: Then please be advised that `\section*` does not reset the `subsection` counter. :)

Comment: `\renewcommand*\numberline[1]{\ifx\relax#1\relax\else\savenumberline{#1.}\fi}` would do it. The `\ifx\relax#1\relax` bit tests if `#1` is empty, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33826/156366).